# Where does ADFS fall in the classifications of authentication systems?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, cas, adfs, blackboard

We are just getting started with implementing **ADFS authentication**, however are still getting our bearings in terms of how to integrate it with other applications and systems.

From what I can tell, the main supported authentication systems for many of the applications we use (I am specifically interested in [Blackboard authentication](http://library.blackboard.com/ref/df5b20ed-ce8d-4428-a595-a0091b23dda3/Content/_admin_server_authentication/authentication_framework_about.htm) at the moment) are ones like **Shibboleth**, **OAuth**, **CAS**, **LDAP** and each application's own authentication implication.

What I'm not sure, however, is *if* (and *where*) **ADFS** falls under these categories. Conceptually, it seems like a type of "Central Authentication System" (**CAS**), but is more similar to **Shibboleth** (also a federated identity management system). Do some of the main categories of authentication overlap each other? From the documentation, I can see:

> **AD FS** provides Web SSO to federated partners outside your organization, which enables their users to have a SSO experience when they access your organization’s Web-based applications.
>
> **The Central Authentication Service (CAS)** is a single sign-on protocol for the web. Its purpose is to permit a user to access multiple applications while providing their credentials (such as userid and password) only once. It also allows web applications to authenticate users without gaining access to a user's security credentials, such as a password. *The name CAS **also refers to a software package that implements this protocol***
>
> **Shibboleth** is among the world's most widely deployed federated identity solutions, connecting users to applications both within and between organizations.

My main question is this:

- Is **ADFS** a *type* of one of those main implementations (like CAS)...
- **or** is it a proprietary version of something like Shibboleth, but can be used interchangeably...
- **or** does it fall in a category *outside* of one of of one of those systems (and hence need to be handled through a manual or custom process)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify:

- Shibboleth is an Identity Provider (IDP) aka Security Token System (STS)
- OAuth is an authentication protocol
- LDAP is an Identity repository

An IDP authenticates against a repository using an authentication protocol.

ADFS is also an Identity Provider (IDP) aka Security Token System (STS)

I've not seen the term "CAS" used in this context.

Shibboleth and ADFS perform the same function and are (in a general sense) interchangeable.

In practice, they aren't because Shibboleth only supports the SAML 2.0 protocol whereas ADFS supports WS-Fed, SAML 2.0 and OpenID Connect / OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Some additions/updates to the accepted answer from rbrayb a few years later:

- Shibboleth IdP is the reference implementation for SAML and also supports  CAS and OpenID Connect.
- Shibboleth SP is the SAML service provider from the same project.
- CAS (Central Authentication Service) is another web-SSO protocol like SAML; it's also the name of the reference implementation, which also supports SAML, OIDC, etc.
- OAuth is an *authorization* standard.
- SAML, CAS, OpenID, Kerberos and other SSO protocols are based on the concept of a [Trusted third party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_third_party).
- LDAP happens to be a service in which, in a given organization, most or everyone already has an account with a password. There is nothing inherently special about it as a server to authenticate against. It could just as well have been a telnet server or web server with basic auth or a SQL server; in any of these cases, the application has to collect the username & password and pass those through to the back-end authentication service, unlike SSO protocols. (LDAP happens to provide a vendor-neutral, non-interactively-focused interface for the authentication, which is part of the reason it's often put to this task rather than the others.)

(I originally tried adding this as a comment but comments do not support the formatting I wanted.)